# How to set the Outgoing WS- Securtiy configurations in soapui using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to set the outgoing WS-Security configuration for a webservice in soapui tool using groovy script.I found the below code.

```
import  com.eviware.soapui.config.OutgoingWssConfig;

OutgoingWssConfig config;
config.setName("Test");
config.setUsername("Test");
config.setPassword("Test123");
config.setActor("someendpoint");
config.setMustUnderstand(true);
```

Can anyone help me on how to assign this config for a particular WSDL project? And let me know if this approach is correct or is there any other alternative to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Althought it is a long time..

```
def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project;
def WssC = project.getWssContainer();
if (!WssC.getOutgoingWssList().contains("TestAutomation-Layer7")) {
 def owss = WssC.addOutgoingWss("TestAutomation-Layer7");
 owss.setActor("TestAutomation");
 owss.setPassword("TestAutomation");
 owss.setUsername("TestAutomation");
 owss.setMustUnderstand(true);
}
```

Found snippet on https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Groovy-to-handle-WSS-Outgoing-Incoming-requests/td-p/118524